# Create A List From a Category Section in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, duplicates

I was wondering if mysql has a way to look at a column and only retrieve the results when it finds a unique column once.  For example

if the table looks like this:

```
id name category
1  test Health
2  carl Health
3  bob  Oscar
4  joe  Technology
```

As you can see their are two rows that could have the same category.  Is their a way to retrieve the result where the array will one only return the category once?

What I am trying to do is get all the categories in the database so I can loop through them later in the code and use them.  For example if I wanted to created a menu, I would want the menu to list all the categories in the menu.

I know I can run

```
SELECT categories FROM dbname
```

but this returns duplicate rows where I only need the cateogry to return once.  Is there a way to do this on the mysql side?

I assume I can just use  php's `array_unique();`

but I feel like this adds more overhead, is this not something MYSQL can do on the backend?

Comment: You can use GROUP BY col

Comment: `select distinct category from table`?

Comment: no I want all the categories, but only need the returned array to list duplicate categories once.  Is there a difference between group by and distinct in performance in mysql? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RamRaider `distinct` is some cases doesn't alway work.

Comment: @DEVPROCB `distinct` as I said to RamRaider isn't alway reliable. As far as performance goes; not really. If your table's properly indexed, I shouldn't see a problem with GROUP BY. You may have to do some complex querying, or a PHP solution if that is the case here.

Comment: if (first on the scene) comments given didn't help solve the question (or should have been submitted as possible solutions in answers), then see the answers below.

Comment: group by worked perfectly @Fred-ii- please submit this as answer so I can get that approved for you.

Comment: @DEVPROCB Glad to hear it; done. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *group by worked perfectly @Fred-ii- please submit this as answer so I can get that approved for you. – DEVPROCB*

As requested by the OP:

You can use `GROUP BY col_of_choice` in order to avoid duplicates be shown in the queried results.

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

By using database normalization, you would create another table with an unique id and the category name and by that link those two together, like

select * from mytable1 
on mytable1.cat = mytable2.id
group by mytable1.cat

You can ofcourse also use group by without multiple tables, but for the structure, I recommend doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categories
FROM dbname ;
```

For various reasons, it is a good idea to have a separate reference table with one row per category.  This helps in many ways:

- Ensures that the category names are consistent ("Technology" versus "tech" for instance).
- Gives a nice list of categories that are available.
- Ensures that a category sticks around, even if no names currently reference it.
- Allows for additional information about categories, such as the first time it appears, or a longer description.

This is recommended.  However, if you still want to leave the category in place as it is, I would recommend an index on `dbname(categories)`.  The query should take advantage of the index.

Comment: I understand, that as this would create a much easier case.  being that the database is already listing categories, it would not be as easy to transform over 20000 records which already has this listed.  Unless you can provide a code that can translate an existing column to reference the separate table and replace it with the id numbers, but I would assume this would require a different question to be asked on stackoverflow as it is not related to the current questions.

Comment: @DEVPROCB . . . That would be a candidate for another question.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, name from dbname GROUP BY categoryname

Hope this will help.

You can even use distinct category.